# IO Exception: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process

Tags: c#, ioexception, pdfrenderer

IO Exception: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process

```
Document document = new Document();

Section section = document.AddSection();
//Added several Paragraphs here

PdfDocumentRenderer pdfRenderer = new PdfDocumentRenderer(false, PdfFontEmbedding.Always);
pdfRenderer.Document = document;
pdfRenderer.RenderDocument();

string filename = "/PDFPro/ITFaultReport.pdf";
pdfRenderer.PdfDocument.Save(Server.MapPath(filename));
```

error is occouring on the last line, when I render more than one pdf after each other.

Comment: Make sure that all object implementing the IDisposable interface is placed within a using statement.